# OpenCL image writes in OS X

Tags: image, textures, opencl

I've been trying to write an OpenCL kernel that populates an OpenCL image with values. However, I've been having problems with some texels not being written to. I can't seem to get the write_image() function to write to texels with different x and y coordinates.

I've created a reduction program here. Hopefully this is straightforward enough to be readable:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <cassert>

#include <OpenCL/OpenCL.h>

const char* clSource[] = {
    "kernel void set(write_only image2d_t image)\n",
    "{\n",
    "    int x = get_global_id(0);\n",
    "    int y = get_global_id(1);\n",
    "    float4 result = float4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);\n",
    "    printf(\"Writing dimensions %d x %d: %d, %d, %d, %d\\n\", x, y,\n",
    "        (int)result.x*255, (int)result.y*255, (int)result.z*255, (int)result.w*255);\n",
    "    write_imagef(image, int2(x, y), result);\n",
    "}\n",
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const unsigned int WIDTH = 3;
    const unsigned int HEIGHT = 3;
    cl_int clError;
    cl_platform_id platform;
    clError = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, nullptr);
    assert(clError == CL_SUCCESS);
    cl_device_id device;
    clError = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device, nullptr);
    assert(clError == CL_SUCCESS);
    cl_context_properties properties[] = {
        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)platform,
        0
    };
    cl_context openCLContext = clCreateContext(properties, 1, &device, nullptr, nullptr, &clError);
    assert(clError == CL_SUCCESS);
    cl_command_queue commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(openCLContext, device, 0, &clError);
    assert(clError == CL_SUCCESS);

    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(openCLContext, sizeof(clSource) / sizeof(const char*), clSource, nullptr, &clError);
    assert(clError == CL_SUCCESS);
    clError = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device, "", nullptr, nullptr);
    assert(clError == CL_SUCCESS);
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "set", &clError);
    assert(clError == CL_SUCCESS);

    cl_image_format imageFormat;
    imageFormat.image_channel_data_type = CL_UNORM_INT8;
    imageFormat.image_channel_order = CL_RGBA;
    cl_image_desc imageDesc;
    imageDesc.image_type = CL_MEM_OBJECT_IMAGE2D;
    imageDesc.image_width = WIDTH;
    imageDesc.image_height = HEIGHT;
    imageDesc.image_depth = 1;
    imageDesc.image_array_size = 1;
    imageDesc.image_row_pitch = 0;
    imageDesc.image_slice_pitch = 0;
    imageDesc.num_mip_levels = 0;
    imageDesc.num_samples = 0;
    imageDesc.buffer = nullptr;
    cl_mem clTexture = clCreateImage(openCLContext, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, &imageFormat, &imageDesc, nullptr, &clError);
    assert(clError == CL_SUCCESS);
    clError = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &clTexture);
    assert(clError == CL_SUCCESS);
    size_t globalWorkOffset[] = {0, 0, 0};
    size_t globalWorkSize[] = {WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0};
    size_t localWorkSize[] = {1, 1, 0};
    cl_event event1;
    clError = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernel, 2, globalWorkOffset, globalWorkSize, localWorkSize, 0, nullptr, &event1);
    assert(clError == CL_SUCCESS);

    unsigned char* bitmap = new unsigned char[WIDTH * HEIGHT * 4];
    size_t origin[] = {0, 0, 0};
    size_t region[] = {WIDTH, HEIGHT, 1};
    cl_event event2;
    clError = clEnqueueReadImage(commandQueue, clTexture, CL_TRUE, origin, region, 0, 0, bitmap, 1, &event1, &event2);

    std::cout << "============================================" << std::endl;
    clError = clWaitForEvents(1, &event2);
    assert(clError == CL_SUCCESS);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j) {
            std::cout << "Reading dimensions " << j << " x " << i << ": ";
            std::cout << static_cast<int>(bitmap[4*(i*WIDTH+j)+0]) << ", ";
            std::cout << static_cast<int>(bitmap[4*(i*WIDTH+j)+1]) << ", ";
            std::cout << static_cast<int>(bitmap[4*(i*WIDTH+j)+2]) << ", ";
            std::cout << static_cast<int>(bitmap[4*(i*WIDTH+j)+3]) << std::endl;
        }
    }
    delete[] bitmap;

    clError = clReleaseEvent(event1);
    assert(clError == CL_SUCCESS);
    clError = clReleaseEvent(event2);
    assert(clError == CL_SUCCESS);
    clError = clReleaseMemObject(clTexture);
    assert(clError == CL_SUCCESS);
    clError = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    assert(clError == CL_SUCCESS);
    clError = clReleaseProgram(program);
    assert(clError == CL_SUCCESS);
    clError = clReleaseCommandQueue(commandQueue);
    assert(clError == CL_SUCCESS);
    clError = clReleaseDevice(device);
    assert(clError == CL_SUCCESS);
    clError = clReleaseContext(openCLContext);
    assert(clError == CL_SUCCESS);
    return 0;
}
```

After all that, here is the output on OS X (10.9):

```
Writing dimensions 0 x 0: 255, 255, 255, 255
Writing dimensions 1 x 0: 255, 255, 255, 255
Writing dimensions 2 x 0: 255, 255, 255, 255
Writing dimensions 0 x 1: 255, 255, 255, 255
Writing dimensions 1 x 1: 255, 255, 255, 255
Writing dimensions 2 x 1: 255, 255, 255, 255
Writing dimensions 0 x 2: 255, 255, 255, 255
Writing dimensions 1 x 2: 255, 255, 255, 255
Writing dimensions 2 x 2: 255, 255, 255, 255
============================================
Reading dimensions 0 x 0: 255, 255, 255, 255
Reading dimensions 1 x 0: 0, 0, 0, 0
Reading dimensions 2 x 0: 0, 0, 0, 0
Reading dimensions 0 x 1: 0, 0, 0, 0
Reading dimensions 1 x 1: 255, 255, 255, 255
Reading dimensions 2 x 1: 0, 0, 0, 0
Reading dimensions 0 x 2: 0, 0, 0, 0
Reading dimensions 1 x 2: 0, 0, 0, 0
Reading dimensions 2 x 2: 255, 255, 255, 255
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I get the same result on a ATI Radeon HD 5750 as I do on a NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M.

[OpenCL to OpenGL texture problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465876/opencl-to-opengl-texture-problems) and [opencl image2d_t doesn't write back values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599986/opencl-image2d-t-doesnt-write-back-values) seem to have similar problems, but neither of those have anything that helps me.

Am I doing something wrong? Or are image writes simply not supported on Mavericks drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the way that you are constructing vector values. Instead of this:

```
typeN(a, b, ..., k)
```

You should be doing this:

```
(typeN)(a, b, ..., k)
```

The former actually causes a compilation error on non-Apple platforms, so I'm not actually sure how Apple's compiler is interpreting that code.

So, for your kernel, the two relevant lines that need to be changed are these:

```
float4 result = float4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
...
write_imagef(image, int2(x, y), result);
```

Which should now become:

```
float4 result = (float4)(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
...
write_imagef(image, (int2)(x, y), result);
```

Comment: GLSL vs OpenCL strikes again!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to compile and run your program successfully with the following kernel change:

```
const char* clSource[] = {
    "__kernel void set(write_only image2d_t image)\n",
    "{\n",
    "    int x = get_global_id(0);\n",
    "    int y = get_global_id(1);\n",
    "    float4 result = (float4)(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);\n",
    "    printf(\"Writing dimensions %d x %d: %d, %d, %d, %d\\n\", x, y,\n",
    "        (int)result.x*255, (int)result.y*255, (int)result.z*255, (int)result.w*255);\n",
    "    write_imagef(image, (int2)(x, y), result);\n",
    "}\n",
};
```

As an example you cannot write float4(1.0.... but you must write it as C style typecast (float4). I have no idea why it even compiled cleanly with your drivers.

Another really weird issue in the output is that your output seems to come from the case where WIDTH and HEIGHT on line 23 were 3. Is the output from a version where it indeed is 3?

Regardless it works fine after the changes.

Comment: Re: 2 vs 3: Yeah, I changed the 2s to 3s before pasting in the output, and forgot to change then in the original source. I've updated the question.

Comment: I'm glad there was an explanation for that; it was weirding me out as well. Thanks for letting us know!